# How to get correct window client area size when using a scrollbar?

Tags: c++, mfc

I created a dialog window and trying to lay out some `EditBoxArray, ComboBoxArray` controls and a `CStatic` label. I set the window position using something like this:

```
SetWindowPos(&wndTop, 10, 10, width, height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

I am able to retrieve the correct client size of the window using `GetClientRect(&rect)`, which doesn't include any borders or title bar. This allows  me to set the label at the bottom of the window like so:

```
GetClientRect(&rect);
y_position = rect.bottom - MY_LABEL_HEIGHT;
....
my_label.SetWindowPos(NULL, x, y_position , width, MY_LABEL_HEIGHT, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

[image]

The problem occurs if I have a client area that is larger than what is currently visible, i.e. requires a scrollbar to scroll the remaining "hidden" area. Using `GetClientRect` returns an incorrect size, causing the label to be positioned not at the bottom of the "whole" client area, but only what is "visible":

[image]
[image]

Using `GetWindowRect` does not work because it also only retrieves the "visible" area + the borders and caption title bars.

Essentially, what I am asking is how do I get the entire visible + invisible client area, without the borders and caption?

Comment: You have to handle your `WM_VSCROLL` message and **redraw/reposition** your label at needed position every time user scrolls.

Comment: Try getting the width and height of the scrollbars and subtract them to GetClientRect . Eg : GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL) and GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXHSCROLL)?

Comment: See [client area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-windows#client-area).

Answer (score 1):

> Essentially, what I am asking is how do I get the entire visible +
>   invisible client area, without the borders and caption?

Call [`CWnd::GetScrollRange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#getscrollrange) to obtain minimum and maximum scroll positions. Their difference is the value you are asking for:

```
int minPos = 0, maxPos = 0;
GetScrollRange( SB_VERT, &minPos, &maxPos );
int scrollableClientHeight = abs( maxPos - minPos );
```

To get scrollable width, replace `SB_VERT` with `SB_HORZ`.

Comment: Are you sure this is right?...Based on the name of the function alone, I deduce it gives the range, i.e. how many clicks it take to scroll from the top->bottom and vice versa. This is not right. I'm looking for the size of the client area.

Comment: @Pangu You are using the wrong term. "Client area" is the *visible* area where content can be drawn (i. e. what `GetClientRect()` returns). What you are looking for is the "virtual" size of the content. You should be able to calculate that from the scroll range. The scroll range doesn't necessarily equal the "number of clicks", e. g. you could have a scroll range of 1000 and increment the scroll position by 10 on every click on the down arrow. It is entirely up to how you handle the `WM_HSCROLL` and `WM_VSCROLL` messages.